# Programmatically Adding Images to Liferay Image Gallery

Tags: liferay

I've created a Liferay portlet that uploads image files to the Image Gallery. I am already able to add and retrieve images from my Liferay server programmatically via IGImageLocalServiceUtil, but I can't seem to see the images in the Image Gallery portlet under Control Panel. I suspect this has something to do with permission issues. Could you please help me find out what's wrong in my code? Thanks.

```
long userId = themeDisplay.getUserId();
long groupId = themeDisplay.getLayout().getGroupId();
String newFilename = "test";
long folderId = 0;
String[] permissions = { "VIEW" };

serviceContext.setCommunityPermissions( permissions );
serviceContext.setGuestPermissions( permissions );

igImage = IGImageLocalServiceUtil.addImage( userId, groupId, folderId, newFilename, "", sourceFile, "image/png" ,serviceContext);
IGImageLocalServiceUtil.addImageResources(igImage, serviceContext.getCommunityPermissions(), serviceContext.getGuestPermissions());
```

Comment: Please, specify what version of Liferay Portal you're using. In the latest versions of Liferay Portal your code will not compile.

Comment: Liferay 6.0.6. Why will this not compile?

Comment: Because in Liferay Portal 6.1 both "Image Gallery" and "Document Library" portlets were combined to "Documents and Media" portlet, so the API was changed and IGImageLocalServiceUtil is no longer exists. But this is not what's your question about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it now. What I was not able to mention in my question is that this portlet is located in the Control Panel. So whenever I get the groupId via themeDisplay.getLayout().getGroupId() instead of the site's own groupId, the image is associated with the Control Panel and not the site.

I should use themeDisplay.getDoAsGroupId() instead of themeDisplay.getLayout().getGroupId() then.